# How to reset the visitor counter to zero after 24 hours?

Tags: php, sql

I have implemented a SQL database to track the number of visitors to my website on a daily basis. The intention is to display this visitor count at the bottom of the website. However, I'm facing an issue where the counter doesn't reset after 24 hours and continues to increment.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me identify the problem in my code.

Here's the relevant code snippet in php where I'm performing the count:

here is the code in php:

```
<?php

$mysqliCounter = new mysqli(
    "localhost","User","pass","website_db"
);

// Check connection
if ($mysqliCounter -> connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqliCounter -> connect_error;
    exit();
}

$mysqliCounter->query('INSERT INTO `views` (`id`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)');
```

After the code, I have implemented the following logic to perform the counting:

```
Today Visitors:
<?php

echo $mysqliCounter->query(
    'SELECT * FROM views WHERE time > \''
    . date("Y-m-d H:i:s" , time() -86400) . "'")
           ->num_rows

?>
```

Comment: Why reset? Don't you want the count for the most recent 24 hours?

Comment: Currently you are counting the last 24 hours, if you want to count since the last midnight you 'd need to calculate the time since last midnight instead of just hardcoding 86400

Comment: @jarlh I just want it to show the today visitors. But after 24hours it won't go zero ans still counts and adds to the previous number (last day visits)

Comment: `CURDATE()` will give you the current date (today) in MySQL

Comment: @mousetail It should be counting the visitors for last 24hrs, but for some reason it does not reset it when a new day starts. My server time base is pacific daylight time. so the new day has started since 45mins ago, yet still the number has not changed.

Comment: Why do you involve time if you only want a date comparison?

Comment: Try this  Today Visitors:
<?php

echo $mysqliCounter->query(
    'SELECT * FROM views WHERE time > \''
    . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "'")
           ->num_rows

?>

Comment: You are contradicting yourself here, either you want the last 24 hours OR you want it to reset at midnight. You can't have both

Comment: @jarlh Because I have had a total view of the website idea. but I am not using it now. maybe in future I will use it. 

To modify it with date, what amendments I should apply?

Comment: @mousetail I want to show the viewers for today (1200 to 2400 of Wednesday may31st) when june 1st starts, I want the counter to start from zero.

Comment: Simply `where time >= curdate()`?

Comment: BTW, time is a poor name for a timestamp column. A timestamp includes both a date and a time.

Comment: Unrelated: what do you need the `id` column for if it is always set to `NULL`?

Comment: @brombeer I need the id column because I want to use the total viewer of the website as well. I can see the id number to verify how many people have visited my website since the code was written.

Comment: @CultureNim `id` needs to have some atomic integer value, `NULL` makes no sense. Also, your code doesn't account for the fact that the same user can visit your site 100 times, but your code will consider that as 100 diff. users, but in reality it is just 1.

Comment: @nice_dev Yes you're right. but this is fine. Each time the page is refreshed, it will consider as a new visit. Like the views on YouTube. A single user can watch the same video tons of times and the view will increase. The visit of the website as of now is not ip based. But if you have the suggestion how to store it by ip, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @jarlh it seems that `where time >= curdate()` is working since when I changed the code, the counter started from single digit (sine the day was started minutes before). I hope it will reset to zero tonight (PDT).

Is there a way to delete the previous rows belonging to the previous days?

Comment: Why would you like to delete data from previous days?!? Keep data forever is the general rule.

Comment: @jarlh I was wondering 10 M of rows might be too much to store. (our viewer might exceed thousands per day). Is it fine to store that much of data? Will it be too big in respect to size of the table?

Comment: If you only store this data to be able to present the count on the site (which I assume since you're only storing date and time), why not use some in-memory storage, like apcu, memcached, redis or something instead? Then you could have the date as key and just ++ that value on each visit. Should be faster than reading/writing to MySQL. If you rather use MySQL, then you can use the same principle, a table with a column for the date (without time) and one for visits count. You then just increment the value for the current date in the table.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @YourCommonSense for better idea.

You have to first convert both the dates into char and compare in `where` condition like below.

```
// Changing `SELECT *` to `SELECT COUNT(*)`, since we dont want any rows to be fetched.
// We need only the total number of rows present based on `where` condition.
// This will avoid unnecessary memory loads and query will executes faster, comparatively.
echo $mysqliCounter->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM views WHERE DATE(time) = CURDATE()')->fetch_row[0];
```

In the above code, we are converting the `timestamp` into `date` and comparing it with current date.

We will get the count of all selected rows based on current date.

*NOTE : The current date will be based on the location of the server*.

**RECOMMENDED IDEA**

*(For small scale applications/website)*

Instead of using your DB, why dont you use filesystem and use one single file for each day.

Creating / Appending a file on each visit.

```
$oldCount = file_get_contents('hits'.date('Ymd')); // We dont need extn.
$newCount = (int)$oldCount++;
$f = fopen('hits'.date('Ymd'), 'w');
flock($f, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB);
fwrite($f, $newCount);
flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);

echo $newCount;
```

PHP's `flock()` function will force the script to follow queque system to write to the same file. filewriter will lock the file and writes to it and unlocks and next filewriter will follow and so on . . .